# Cakephp If id exists update, else create

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to update the record if the ID is exists in my database. If ID not exists create record. This is my code in my Controller add function

```
public function add () {

    $googleCategory = $this->request->data;

    foreach ($googleCategory as $key => $value) {
        if(empty($value['category'])){
            unset($value);
        }

        $this->AccountShopMeta->create();

        $data['shop_id'] = $value['shop_id'];
        $data['name'] = $value['category'];
        $data['value'] = $value['url_key'];
        $data['tag'] = '';

        if($this->AccountShopMeta->save($data)){
            $account_shop_meta = $this->AccountShopMeta->read();
            $this->set($account_shop_meta);
            $this->set('_serialize', array_keys($account_shop_meta));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: which id of which table ?? is that shop_id of AccountShopMeta ?

Comment: id of AccountShopMeta @ManoharKhadka

Answer (score 1):

if i understood what you are asking may be this will help you. Do not use Create. if id exist in given array ,updatation automatically will be done on that ID. Otherwise new row will be created.

```
public function add () {

$googleCategory = $this->request->data;

foreach ($googleCategory as $key => $value) {
    if(empty($value['category'])){
        unset($value);
    }
   if(!empty($value[id])){
      $data['id']=$value[id];
   }


    $data['shop_id'] = $value['shop_id'];
    $data['name'] = $value['category'];
    $data['value'] = $value['url_key'];
    $data['tag'] = '';

    if($this->AccountShopMeta->save($data)){
        $account_shop_meta = $this->AccountShopMeta->read();
        $this->set($account_shop_meta);
        $this->set('_serialize', array_keys($account_shop_meta));
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if id not exists it comes as empty, in such case add following conditions within foreach and at least above save action:

```
foreach ($googleCategory as $key => $value) {
  if(isset($value['id']) && !empty($value['id'])){
     $this->AccountShopMeta->id = $value['id'];
     // your remaining code within loop here
     //
  }
}
```

Do not forget to send data for id form your view(form) if exists..

Comment: you have miss a single quote `empty($value['id])` will be `empty($value['id'])`

Comment: Oh I see..i corrected it.